# Log out facebook when user doesn't give permission

Tags: php, facebook

My app (facebook-php) uploads images to the user's wall, and to a page. Everything works fine, even logging out after uploading.

There is a problem when the user logs in with his email and pw, and then presses cancel when asked for permission to get birthday etc. This moment, the user is logged in, but I can't make a valid logout link

```
$params = array( 'next' => 'http://localhost/index.php' );
$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
```

(access_token is "0").

The only way to logout is to go to facebook.com and click logout. Is there another way I can logout the user?

Answer (score 0):

No, the user decides when he is logged out or logged in on Facebook, you cannot decide for him on this issue or even add such a button.

You need to adapt your application to handle that case instead, you cannot log out a user, but you can know if that user is logged in or not, and display your application accordingly.

Comment: Problem here is, that there will be multiple people logging in and out. If someone doesn't give permission, and continues the app, the next person that will try to login, will still be working on the previous guy's facebook. Is there a way maybe to force facebook to show the login page?

Comment: What?! If everyone uses a different computer, they won't be on each other's facebook account.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The app will run during an event, on a computer that is accessible for all visitors...

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible, you'll need to ask the users to log out.

Comment: make them surf the web in "anonymous mode" like you can do in chrome, this will force the logout at the end of the session of the brwser

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but I worked around it. Installed an extension which enables me to inject the facebookpage with css. I disable the cancel button by setting it's display to 'none'...